# Why is my conditional statement in Swift not working?

Tags: ios, swift

```
var word1array = [colorwordw1, colorwordg1, colorwordb1]
var word1 = word1array [ofThree()]
```

`[ofThree()]` function is:

```
func ofThree() -> Int {
    return Int(arc4random() % 3)
}
```

For some reason, the following conditional statement always evaluates as true

```
 @IBAction func White1Action(sender: AnyObject) {

    if (word1 == colorwordw1) {


        [moveTilesDown()]


        [RandomPlacementTwo()]


     }
```

What is wrong with my code?

Thanks

inits:

```
var colorwordw1 = "White"
var word1 = "White"
```

more context

```
var colorwordsarray:[String] = ["Blue","Red","Green","Yellow","Gray","Cyan","Magenta","Orange","Purple","White","Brown","Black"]

var colorwordw1 = colorwordsarray[random12]

random12 = ofTwelve()

func ofTwelve() -> Int {
    return Int(arc4random() % 12)
}
```

Here is all the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {



    @IBOutlet weak var whiteTile1: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var greyTile1: UIButton!


    @IBOutlet weak var blackTile1: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var whiteTile2: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var greyTile2: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var blackTile2: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var whiteTile3: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var greyTile3: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var blackTile3: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var whiteTile4: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var greyTile4: UIButton!


    @IBOutlet weak var blackTile4: UIButton!


    @IBOutlet weak var whiteTile5: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var greyTile5: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var blackTile5: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var colorText5: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var colorText4: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var colorText3: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var colorText2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var colorText1: UILabel!



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }



// function returns 1-3 randomly

    func ofThree() -> Int {
        return Int(arc4random() % 3)
    }

// variable array for color, with three options - used with above function to later define word variable

    var wordarray:[String] = ["White", "Grey", "Black"]

//     var ofThree = Int(arc4random() % 3)

    func ofTwelve() -> Int {
        return Int(arc4random() % 12)
    }

    var colorarray = [UIColor.blueColor(),UIColor.redColor(),UIColor.greenColor(),UIColor.yellowColor(),UIColor.grayColor(),UIColor.cyanColor(),UIColor.magentaColor(),UIColor.orangeColor(),UIColor.purpleColor(),UIColor.whiteColor(),UIColor.brownColor(),UIColor.blackColor()]

    var colorwordsarray:[String] = ["Blue","Red","Green","Yellow","Gray","Cyan","Magenta","Orange","Purple","White","Brown","Black"]

    // init word variable

    var word = "White"
    var word1 = "White"
    var word2 = "White"
    var word3 = "White"
    var word4 = "White"
    var word5 = "White"
    var colorw1 = UIColor.whiteColor()
    var colorw2 = UIColor.whiteColor()
    var colorw3 = UIColor.whiteColor()
    var colorw4 = UIColor.whiteColor()
    var colorw5 = UIColor.whiteColor()
    var colorg1 = UIColor.whiteColor()
    var colorg2 = UIColor.whiteColor()
    var colorg3 = UIColor.whiteColor()
    var colorg4 = UIColor.whiteColor()
    var colorg5 = UIColor.whiteColor()
    var colorb1 = UIColor.whiteColor()
    var colorb2 = UIColor.whiteColor()
    var colorb3 = UIColor.whiteColor()
    var colorb4 = UIColor.whiteColor()
    var colorb5 = UIColor.whiteColor()
    var colorwordw1 = "White"
    var colorwordw2 = "White"
    var colorwordw3 = "White"
    var colorwordw4 = "White"
    var colorwordw5 = "White"
    var colorwordg1 = "White"
    var colorwordg2 = "White"
    var colorwordg3 = "White"
    var colorwordg4 = "White"
    var colorwordg5 = "White"
    var colorwordb1 = "White"
    var colorwordb2 = "White"
    var colorwordb3 = "White"
    var colorwordb4 = "White"
    var colorwordb5 = "White"

    var random12 = 12


 func moveTilesDown(){

    colorText5.center.y += 142
    colorText4.center.y += 142
    colorText3.center.y += 142
    colorText2.center.y += 142
    colorText1.center.y += 142
    whiteTile1.center.y += 142
    whiteTile2.center.y += 142
    whiteTile3.center.y += 142
    whiteTile4.center.y += 142
    whiteTile5.center.y += 142
    greyTile1.center.y += 142
    greyTile2.center.y += 142
    greyTile3.center.y += 142
    greyTile4.center.y += 142
    greyTile5.center.y += 142
    blackTile1.center.y += 142
    blackTile2.center.y += 142
    blackTile3.center.y += 142
    blackTile4.center.y += 142
    blackTile5.center.y += 142
    [self.view .bringSubviewToFront(colorText1)]
    [self.view .bringSubviewToFront(colorText2)]
    [self.view .bringSubviewToFront(colorText3)]
    [self.view .bringSubviewToFront(colorText4)]
    [self.view .bringSubviewToFront(colorText5)]

    // get new random word and update label








     // if title row is too low, move row to the top

    if (whiteTile1.center.y >= 601) {
        whiteTile1.center.y = -71
        greyTile1.center.y = -71
        blackTile1.center.y = -71
        colorText1.center.y = -142
        random12 = ofTwelve()
        var colorw1 = colorarray[random12]
        var colorwordw1 = colorwordsarray[random12]
        random12 = ofTwelve()
        var colorg1 = colorarray[random12]
        var colorwordg1 = colorwordsarray[random12]
        random12 = ofTwelve()
        var colorb1 = colorarray[random12]
        var colorwordb1 = colorwordsarray[random12]
        var word1array = [colorwordw1, colorwordg1, colorwordb1]
        var word1 = word1array [ofThree()]
        whiteTile1.backgroundColor = colorw1
        greyTile1.backgroundColor = colorg1
        blackTile1.backgroundColor = colorb1
        [self.view .bringSubviewToFront(colorText1)]
        colorText1.text = word1
        colorText1.hidden = false



    }

//    if colorw1 == colorg1 {
//        
//        random12 = ofTwelve()
//        var colorw1 = colorarray[random12]
//        var colorwordw1 = colorwordsarray[random12]
//        var word1array = [colorwordw1, colorwordg1, colorwordb1]
//        word1 = word1array [ofThree()]
//        whiteTile1.backgroundColor = colorw1
//    }
//        
//    } else {
//        
//        if colorw1 == colorb1 {
//
//        random12 = ofTwelve()
//        var colorw1 = colorarray[random12]
//        var colorwordw1 = colorwordsarray[random12]
//        var word1array = [colorwordw1, colorwordg1, colorwordb1]
//        word1 = word1array [ofThree()]
//        whiteTile1.backgroundColor = colorw1
//        
//        }
//        
//    }
    if (whiteTile2.center.y >= 600) {
        whiteTile2.center.y = -71
        greyTile2.center.y = -71
        blackTile2.center.y = -71
        colorText2.center.y = -142
        random12 = ofTwelve()
        var colorw2 = colorarray[random12]
        var colorwordw2 = colorwordsarray[random12]
        random12 = ofTwelve()
        var colorg2 = colorarray[random12]
        var colorwordg2 = colorwordsarray[random12]
        random12 = ofTwelve()
        var colorb2 = colorarray[random12]
        var colorwordb2 = colorwordsarray[random12]
        var word2array = [colorwordw2, colorwordg2, colorwordb2]
        var word2 = word2array [ofThree()]
        whiteTile2.backgroundColor = colorw2
        greyTile2.backgroundColor = colorg2
        blackTile2.backgroundColor = colorb2
        [self.view .bringSubviewToFront(colorText2)]
        colorText2.text = word2
        colorText2.hidden = false


    }
    if (whiteTile3.center.y >= 600) {
        whiteTile3.center.y = -71
        greyTile3.center.y = -71
        blackTile3.center.y = -71
        colorText3.center.y = -142
        random12 = ofTwelve()
        var colorw3 = colorarray[random12]
        var colorwordw3 = colorwordsarray[random12]
        random12 = ofTwelve()
        var colorg3 = colorarray[random12]
        var colorwordg3 = colorwordsarray[random12]
        random12 = ofTwelve()
        var colorb3 = colorarray[random12]
        var colorwordb3 = colorwordsarray[random12]
        var word3array = [colorwordw3, colorwordg3, colorwordb3]
        var word3 = word3array [ofThree()]
        whiteTile3.backgroundColor = colorw3
        greyTile3.backgroundColor = colorg3
        blackTile3.backgroundColor = colorb3
        [self.view .bringSubviewToFront(colorText3)]
        colorText3.text = word3
        colorText3.hidden = false


    }
    if (whiteTile4.center.y >= 600) {
        whiteTile4.center.y = -71
        greyTile4.center.y = -71
        blackTile4.center.y = -71
        colorText4.center.y = -142
        random12 = ofTwelve()
        var colorw4 = colorarray[random12]
        var colorwordw4 = colorwordsarray[random12]
        random12 = ofTwelve()
        var colorg4 = colorarray[random12]
        var colorwordg4 = colorwordsarray[random12]
        random12 = ofTwelve()
        var colorb4 = colorarray[random12]
        var colorwordb4 = colorwordsarray[random12]
        var word4array = [colorwordw4, colorwordg4, colorwordb4]
        var word4 = word4array [ofThree()]
        whiteTile4.backgroundColor = colorw4
        greyTile4.backgroundColor = colorg4
        blackTile4.backgroundColor = colorb4
        [self.view .bringSubviewToFront(colorText4)]
        colorText4.text = word4
        colorText4.hidden = false


    }
    if (whiteTile5.center.y >= 600) {
        whiteTile5.center.y = -71
        greyTile5.center.y = -71
        blackTile5.center.y = -71
        colorText5.center.y = -142
        random12 = ofTwelve()
        var colorw5 = colorarray[random12]
        var colorwordw5 = colorwordsarray[random12]
        random12 = ofTwelve()
        var colorg5 = colorarray[random12]
        var colorwordg5 = colorwordsarray[random12]
        random12 = ofTwelve()
        var colorb5 = colorarray[random12]
        var colorwordb5 = colorwordsarray[random12]
        var word5array = [colorwordw5, colorwordg5, colorwordb5]
        var word5 = word5array [ofThree()]
        whiteTile5.backgroundColor = colorw5
        greyTile5.backgroundColor = colorg5
        blackTile5.backgroundColor = colorb5
        [self.view .bringSubviewToFront(colorText5)]
        colorText5.text = word5
        colorText5.hidden = false
    }

    }








// Below are the button actions.  First they check if the correct color was selected.  If false, no action.  If true, it moves all tiles down and selects a new color randomly and updates the label accordingly.  After that, it calls the RandomPlacement function that scrambles the order of the next row of tiles displayed.




    @IBAction func White4Action(sender: AnyObject) {
//        if (whiteTile4.center.y >= 490 && word == "White") {

        if (word4 == colorwordw4){


            [moveTilesDown()]


            [RandomPlacementFive()]


        }





    }
    @IBAction func Grey4Action(sender: AnyObject) {

        if (word4 == colorwordg4) {


            [moveTilesDown()]


            [RandomPlacementFive()]

        }



    }

    @IBAction func Black4Action(sender: AnyObject) {

        if (word4 == colorwordb4) {


            [moveTilesDown()]


            [RandomPlacementFive()]
        }



    }


    @IBAction func White3Action(sender: AnyObject) {

        if (word3 == colorwordw3){


            [moveTilesDown()]


            [RandomPlacementFour()]



        }



    }
    @IBAction func Grey3Action(sender: AnyObject) {

        if (word3 == colorwordg3) {


            [moveTilesDown()]


            [RandomPlacementFour()]



        }



    }
    @IBAction func Black3Action(sender: AnyObject) {

        if (word3 == colorwordb3) {


            [moveTilesDown()]


            [RandomPlacementFour()]

        }



    }

    @IBAction func White2Action(sender: AnyObject) {

        if (word2 == colorwordw2) {

            [moveTilesDown()]


            [RandomPlacementThree()]


        }



    }

    @IBAction func Grey2Action(sender: AnyObject) {

        if (word2 == colorwordg2) {


            [moveTilesDown()]


            [RandomPlacementThree()]


        }



    }

    @IBAction func Black2Action(sender: AnyObject) {

        if (word2 == colorwordb2) {


            [moveTilesDown()]


            [RandomPlacementThree()]


        }



    }

    @IBAction func White1Action(sender: AnyObject) {

        if (word1 == colorwordw1) {


            [moveTilesDown()]


            [RandomPlacementTwo()]


         }

    }
    @IBAction func Grey1Action(sender: AnyObject) {

        if (word1 == colorwordg1) {

            [moveTilesDown()]


            [RandomPlacementTwo()]


      }

    }

    @IBAction func Black1Action(sender: AnyObject) {

        if (word1 == colorwordb1) {

            [moveTilesDown()]


            [RandomPlacementTwo()]


             }

    }

    @IBAction func White5Action(sender: AnyObject) {


        if (word5 == colorwordw5) {


            [moveTilesDown()]


            [RandomPlacementOne()]


        }
    }


    @IBAction func Grey5Action(sender: AnyObject) {

        if (word5 == colorwordg5) {



            [moveTilesDown()]


            [RandomPlacementOne()]




    }
    }


    @IBAction func Black5Action(sender: AnyObject) {

        if (word5 == colorwordb5) {




        [moveTilesDown()]

            [RandomPlacementOne()]

        }



}



    func RandomPlacementOne(){


        // question = wordarray[ofThree()]


        var RandomNumber = arc4random() % 6
        switch(RandomNumber){
        case 0:
            blackTile1.center.x = 161
            whiteTile1.center.x = 268
            greyTile1.center.x = 54


        case 1:
            blackTile1.center.x = 268
            whiteTile1.center.x = 161
            greyTile1.center.x = 54


        case 2:
            blackTile1.center.x = 54
            whiteTile1.center.x = 268
            greyTile1.center.x = 161


        case 3:
            blackTile1.center.x = 54
            whiteTile1.center.x = 161
            greyTile1.center.x = 268


        case 4:
            blackTile1.center.x = 268
            whiteTile1.center.x = 54
            greyTile1.center.x = 161


        case 5:
            blackTile1.center.x = 161
            whiteTile1.center.x = 54
            greyTile1.center.x = 268


        default: break



    }
//         [colorWord()]

}


    // Below are the random placement functions.  It first chooses a random number out of 6 and depending on the number, reorders the colors on the row.

    func RandomPlacementTwo(){


        // question = wordarray[ofThree()]


        var RandomNumber = arc4random() % 6
        switch(RandomNumber){
        case 0:
            blackTile2.center.x = 161
            whiteTile2.center.x = 268
            greyTile2.center.x = 54


        case 1:
            blackTile2.center.x = 268
            whiteTile2.center.x = 161
            greyTile2.center.x = 54


        case 2:
            blackTile2.center.x = 54
            whiteTile2.center.x = 268
            greyTile2.center.x = 161


        case 3:
            blackTile2.center.x = 54
            whiteTile2.center.x = 161
            greyTile2.center.x = 268


        case 4:
            blackTile2.center.x = 268
            whiteTile2.center.x = 54
            greyTile2.center.x = 161


        case 5:
            blackTile2.center.x = 161
            whiteTile2.center.x = 54
            greyTile2.center.x = 268


        default: break



        }
//         [colorWord()]

}
    func RandomPlacementThree(){


        // question = wordarray[ofThree()]


        var RandomNumber = arc4random() % 6
        switch(RandomNumber){
        case 0:
            blackTile3.center.x = 161
            whiteTile3.center.x = 268
            greyTile3.center.x = 54


        case 1:
            blackTile3.center.x = 268
            whiteTile3.center.x = 161
            greyTile3.center.x = 54


        case 2:
            blackTile3.center.x = 54
            whiteTile3.center.x = 268
            greyTile3.center.x = 161


        case 3:
            blackTile3.center.x = 54
            whiteTile3.center.x = 161
            greyTile3.center.x = 268


        case 4:
            blackTile3.center.x = 268
            whiteTile3.center.x = 54
            greyTile3.center.x = 161


        case 5:
            blackTile3.center.x = 161
            whiteTile3.center.x = 54
            greyTile3.center.x = 268


        default: break



        }

//         [colorWord()]

}
    func RandomPlacementFour(){



        // question = wordarray[ofThree()]


        var RandomNumber = arc4random() % 6
        switch(RandomNumber){
        case 0:
            blackTile4.center.x = 161
            whiteTile4.center.x = 268
            greyTile4.center.x = 54


        case 1:
            blackTile4.center.x = 268
            whiteTile4.center.x = 161
            greyTile4.center.x = 54


        case 2:
            blackTile4.center.x = 54
            whiteTile4.center.x = 268
            greyTile4.center.x = 161


        case 3:
            blackTile4.center.x = 54
            whiteTile4.center.x = 161
            greyTile4.center.x = 268


        case 4:
            blackTile4.center.x = 268
            whiteTile4.center.x = 54
            greyTile4.center.x = 161


        case 5:
            blackTile4.center.x = 161
            whiteTile4.center.x = 54
            greyTile4.center.x = 268


        default: break



        }

// [colorWord()]
}
    func RandomPlacementFive(){

        // question = wordarray[ofThree()]


        var RandomNumber = arc4random() % 6
        switch(RandomNumber){
        case 0:
            blackTile5.center.x = 161
            whiteTile5.center.x = 268
            greyTile5.center.x = 54


        case 1:
            blackTile5.center.x = 268
            whiteTile5.center.x = 161
            greyTile5.center.x = 54


        case 2:
            blackTile5.center.x = 54
            whiteTile5.center.x = 268
            greyTile5.center.x = 161


        case 3:
            blackTile5.center.x = 54
            whiteTile5.center.x = 161
            greyTile5.center.x = 268


        case 4:
            blackTile5.center.x = 268
            whiteTile5.center.x = 54
            greyTile5.center.x = 161


        case 5:
            blackTile5.center.x = 161
            whiteTile5.center.x = 54
            greyTile5.center.x = 268


        default: break



        }
//        [colorWord()]


}

}
```

Comment: Where is `colorwordw1` initialized?  Where is `word1` initialized?  Where are they declared that this function can see them?  Have you used the debugger to check their values at run time?

Comment: i posted the initialization lines.. but the variable changes after every button press.  They are initialized in the beginning of the program.  I didn't check the debugger because the the colors display as expected (the variables define the colors)

Comment: Your question has zero context.  You posted a declaration/initialization of `word1`, but nothing for `colorwordw1`, and even if you do, you show no context to let answerers try to figure out what state the variables could be in, and not enough context for someone to rebuild your scenario.  On top of this, you haven't bothered using a debugger to get any more information about the variable.

Comment: And you've edited some information at the bottom that makes no sense given the information at the top (`word1` is declared twice?  Which context is each declared in?  Which one is your function seeing?)  And your added information suggests that the two variables you're comparing are identical strings... why would they ever evaluate as unequal?

Comment: Swift requires that variables are initialized.  You asked about that so I posted it.  It serves no relevance other than initialization, obviously the value changes because of the more relevant code I posted earlier.   I know you are an active user, but I am not that stupid.

Comment: i posted more context as you requested.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you just post, in a single snippet, the entire context of the problem?  Starting with `class YourViewController: UIViewController {` and ending with the closing brace of the class definition?  And then snip out anything that's completely irrelevent?  You're asking us to **guess** at the scope of your variables.  You're asking us to **guess** at what value your variables that are "always equal" has.  Ashraf Tawfeeq's answer suggests you might be using random wrong.  Have you checked what values your random function is actually returning?  You have a LOT of information that's on your monitor

Comment: The program displays 3 random colored buttons.  The variables mentioned above display this random color.  I know the variable is not the same because I visibly see the random colors displaying correctly.  In fact, everything about this is working, except for the fact it works even when the wrong color is pressed.  Which is why I know there is something wrong with the conditional.

Comment: the program is not that complex, so I thought it must be something obvious I am doing wrong.  I pasted all code that I think is relevant, but if there is something more you want to see just tell me.

Comment: That's fine that you *know* it's wrong.  But unless you can show us the correct context, it's impossible for anyone to spot what's actually wrong.  The conditional can only be "wrong" if you've implemented a custom operator.  In which case, you need to show us that custom implementation.  Otherwise, the values aren't what you suspect they are.  Use your debugger, or add enough context so I can use mine, or delete the question.  Do you want free help or not?

Comment: I already told you what I want to see.  Take your *entire* view controller class and only delete the purely irrelevent variables and methods.  Leave the entire structure of the class together though.

Comment: ok i pasted all the code

Comment: Well, once you fix this, I **highly** recommend CodeReview...

Comment: ok, I can check that out, but do you have any other comment about the code I posted?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever value you assign your variable at the time you declare it is the value it will still have by the time a button is pressed.  You have nothing in place that will change the value of any button before a button is pressed.  No method in your class is called as part of a view controller life cycle event (and there are no constructors).

So, when the first button is pressed, `word1`, which is assigned the value `"White"` and `colorwordw1`, which is also assigned the value `"White"` will be the same value.  That means `==` should return `true` for them.

Once a button is tapped, it looks like all of the buttons call the `moveTilesDown` function.  I assume that perhaps you expect this function to be changing the values of your instance variables that are compared in the button press?  But it's not changing any instance variables.

Look at the syntax highlighting in this screenshot of your code I pasted into Xcode:

[image]

The variables in green are instance variables.  The variables in white are variables scoped only to the function (and in this specific case, they're scoped only within the `if` block here).

We're declaring 8 new variables in this `if` block which coincidentally have the same name as some of our instance variables.

If we go back to the methods that handle the button touches and set a break point (or simply print the values), we'll find that the variables are all always `"White"`.  Nothign ever changes the variable.

*However*, your `moveTilesDown` method *does* take care of changing the colors and text on your buttons.  But your button touch method don't compare the text on the button with a local variable, or the color of the button to something, it compares to variables which never change.

So, if we're intending to change our instance variables in our `moveTilesDown` method, we need to change these 8 lines that start with `var` to referring to the instance variable rather than creating new local variables.

For example:

```
if (whiteTile1.center.y >= 601) {
    whiteTile1.center.y = -71
    greyTile1.center.y = -71
    blackTile1.center.y = -71
    colorText1.center.y = -142
    random12 = ofTwelve()
    colorw1 = colorarray[random12]
    colorwordw1 = colorwordsarray[random12]
    random12 = ofTwelve()
    colorg1 = colorarray[random12]
    colorwordg1 = colorwordsarray[random12]
    random12 = ofTwelve()
    colorb1 = colorarray[random12]
    colorwordb1 = colorwordsarray[random12]
    word1array = [colorwordw1, colorwordg1, colorwordb1]
    word1 = word1array [ofThree()]
    whiteTile1.backgroundColor = colorw1
    greyTile1.backgroundColor = colorg1
    blackTile1.backgroundColor = colorb1
    [self.view .bringSubviewToFront(colorText1)]
    colorText1.text = word1
    colorText1.hidden = false
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed reply.  Your code fixed it.  I did have to declare/initialize word1array as an array, otherwise your code did throw up a couple of errors, but you did it..  Thanks for your patience. This is my first Xcode project and prior to this I had no programming experience aside from working with Flash almost 15 years ago, so I am learning.  I am in your debt, sir.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot upvote you yet because my rep is too low.  And I apparently cannot choose your answer as the correct one.  But, when my rep gets to 5, I will do that.  I am still learning how to generate rep here.

Comment: I found the invisible "accept answer" button.   I am running Safari on a Mac Book Air , and apparently anyone with low rep cannot see the "accept answer" button on this site.  I literally had to click an empty area of the page under your vote number.  They should fix this.